# How to store methods of the class A in const dictionary of the class A?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, constants

Let's assume that we have class A defined as

```
class A:
   KEY_A = "KEY_A"
   KEY_B = "KEY_B"

   __methodDict = {KEY_A : __method_a,
                 KEY_B : __method_b}

   def __init__(self):
     self.variableABC = 'ABC'

   def __method_a(self):
      print("method a")

   def __method_b(self):
      print("method b")
```

When the code above is run, the compilation time error will inform user that __method_a does not exist. No, it does not because python does not have any idea about the class A's internals.

So, my question is, how can I define __methodDict as constant of the class A to store class A's __method_a and method_b?

Comment: You could make those methods class methods by decorating them with `@classmethod` then reference them as `A.__method_a`. However, that limits there use a little. If you need them to be instance methods you can define an initializer `__init__` and inside it set `self.__methodDict = { ... self.__method_a ... }`

Comment: @rayepps at that time `A` isn't defined

Comment: Try moving the referenced methods before the `__methodDict` definition, it should work now

Comment: @dcg, Thank you! It worked indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No compilation-time error occurs. What you are seeing is a *runtime error*, a `NameError`. The key fact to understand here is that a class definition statement isn't a declaration, it is *executable code*, you can think of it as syntactic sugar for a call to the `type` constructor. A class is just an object, like any other. In this case, you can fix your name error by moving the dict defintion after the methods are defined:

```
class A:
   KEY_A = "KEY_A"
   KEY_B = "KEY_B"

   def __init__(self):
     self.variableABC = 'ABC'

   def __method_a(self):
      print("method a")

   def __method_b(self):
      print("method b")

   __methodDict = {KEY_A : __method_a,
                 KEY_B : __method_b}
```

This will run without the runtime `NameError`

Note, Python doesn't have constants. And I should probably also mention, double-underscore name-mangling is not the same as a private variable, it is there to prevent name-collisions in subclasses. So those double-underscores are probably not necessary.

Comment: Yes, while double underscore does not mean that method is private, it still can help to distinguish between methods meant to be public and private. This is the thing I am missing most of all in python. AS well as constants.

Comment: @user1415536  conventionally, a *single* underscore denotes "private", i.e., something not meant to be part of the public API.

Comment: My mistake. I probably should read style guide again. It was a while since the last time I used python.